# How to test webvr without 3D VR goggles?

Tags: webvr

I need to display a webvr side-by-side on my computer monitor and I don't have 3D VR goggles. How can I display a webvr on my computer screen with the left and right display?

For example, I downloaded chrome and enabled webvr and restarted it and then went here to the examples.

https://webvr.info/samples/

I click on hello web-vr and it says "WebVR supported, but no VRDisplays found."

This one uses Polyfill and shows what I want to see, just for demo to show you here. I don't really want Polyfill used.

https://webvr.info/samples/02-stereo-rendering.html?polyfill=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with using this WebVR emulator extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webvr-api-emulation/gbdnpaebafagioggnhkacnaaahpiefil
and enabling the null driver for SteamVR. The latter can be done by editing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\steamvr.vrsettings". Here's what mine looks like:

```
{
    "steamvr" : {
        "forcedDriver": "null"
    },
    "driver_null" : {
        "enable": true,
        "windowWidth": 1920,
        "windowHeight": 1080
     }
}
```

When you run SteamVR, it should automatically run a display mirror. You can then run the WebVR page, and tinker with the emulator to adjust the position and rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to emulate an OpenVR device. Install SteamVR and try one of the many emulation options, there are Cardboard/OpenVR translators (never used one of these) and a [null device](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamVR/steamvr.vrsettings) [(description)](https://steamcommunity.com/app/358720/discussions/0/350532536102645825/) that will probably satisfy webvr.